# Hyperledger Explorer: How to call API from an client?

Tags: react-redux

My server is already configured for CORS and it is running in other react-redux application.

Now I am trying to call a sample API from [Hyperledger Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer). I've written a function for calling to my API server. The code for calling my API server is given here:

```js
import agent from 'superagent';
import {showHomePage} from './actions';

const payload = {
 "startTime":"2019-12-10 21:12",
 "endTime":"2020-01-31 20:50"
};

const requestToGoogle = () => dispatch => {

 agent.post('http://103.23.42.198:9099/api/certificate/list').send(payload).
 then( response => {
   console.log(response);
   dispatch(showHomePage(response))
  }
 ).catch(error => {
  console.log('error found## ' + error);
 });
};


export default requestToGoogle;
```

When I am calling the API server using post/get function I always the the following error:

> Refused to connect to 'http://103.23.42.198:9099/api/certificate/list' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> error found## Error: Request has been terminated
>   Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

How can I call my API server and get response from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is configured that we can't fetch any content from another server. So I created a router function inside ***app/rest/*** folder. Then I call that router function from client side. Just replaced `agent.post('http://103.23.42.198:9099/api/certificate/list')` with `post('/api/certificate/list')`. Here post is imported from `'../../../services/request'`.